# Unity button hover animation plays when the scene starts, not when the mouse pointer is over the gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

ive made a hoveron and hoveroff animation which when the mouse pointer is over the button (hovering) it slides the button out slightly to the left, and hover off the opposite animation where it slides back to its original position.

however it plays hoveron when the scene starts and i cant get hoveroff to play at all, anybody know a fix?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class hoverscript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{
    public RectTransform NewGameMenuButton;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    NewGameMenuButton.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Hover Off");
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        NewGameMenuButton.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Hover On");
    
    }

     public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        NewGameMenuButton.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("Hover Off");
  
    }
}
```

[image: the button itself]

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't dragged the button on the script.

Comment: You can add a comment to your question or delete your question, this is really not an answer. This is a best practice for SO.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran. If the OP finds an answer they should post it as an answer - not as a comment. Deleting the question is also an option.